# What's the optimization rule of rust vectorization?

Tags: rust, vectorization, llvm, auto-vectorization

I have some code snippets, some of those are auto-vectorized while some are not. It's confusing.

I test them on my macbook pro m1, and execute command `cargo rustc --bin rust-playground -- -C opt-level=3 --emit=llvm-ir` to get the llvm-ir and analyze whether it's auto-vectorized.

First 3 of them have the same caller code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
    ];
    println!("{:?}", auto_vec(&a));
}
```

1. not auto-vectorized

```rust
pub fn auto_vec(a: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut p = 0;
    for i in a {
        p += i;
    }
    p
}
```

2. auto-vectorized

```rust
pub fn auto_vec(a: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut p = 0;
    let mut q = 0;
    // can see some instructions like 'add <4 x i32>' and 'mul <4 x i32>'
    for i in a {
        p += i;
        q += i * i;
    }
    q - p
}
```

3. not auto-vectorized

```rust
pub fn auto_vec(a: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut p = 0;
    let mut q = 0;
    // can't see some instructions like 'add <4 x i32>' or 'mul <4 x i32>'
    for i in a {
        p += i;
        q += i * i;
    }
    // do not access p and q
    0
}
```

4. merge the `auto_vec` function into main, partial auto-vectorized

```rust
fn main() {
    // can see store <4 x i32>
    let a = [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
    ];
    let mut p = 0;
    let mut q = 0;
    // can't see add <4 x i32> or mul <4 x i32>
    for i in a {
        p += i; 
        q += i * i;
    }
    println!("{:?}", q - p);
}
```

5. and I find that the length of the array may affect the result -- if it's too short, it seems that the compiler won't optimize it.

I'm thankful if someone helps me.

Comment: As far as I know optimization is implementation defined and as such can change with every compiler version, so there is no hard rule when something gets vectorized. In other words it can't be relied upon and any answer is tied to the specific compiler version. As such I don't believe your question can reasonably be answered in the scope of SO.

Comment: The third version doesn't vectorize because it removes the loop completely, which is definitely faster than vectorizing it.